# Simple but tricky permutation question

Tags: combinatorics

There are $72$ perspective home-buyers, and $300$ houses in a line. However, assume only sixty of the people purchase a house. Among the people are Oscar and Patricia, they were divorced recently, and refuse to ever be neighbors.  How many possible housing arrangements are there?

Remember that neither Patricia nor Oscar are necessarily part of the $60$.

I reached the answer of: $_{72}C_{60} \cdot \mathbb{P}(300,60)-2\left(_{70}C_{58}\right)\cdot\mathbb{P}(299,59)$, but I don't think I'm correct...

Comment: What relevance is there to the 12 buyers who aren't buying? Why call them buyers if they aren't planning to buy?

Comment: @Arthur Edited it, and the significance is a greater number of permutations, as there exists 60 slots for 72 people to rotate around in.

Comment: Does "neighbor" mean adjacent house, or nearest house on either side ?

Comment: Adjacent, the houses are in a line.

Comment: But we are concerned with only $60$ occupied houses in a line of $300$ houses, that is why I am asking

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  The houses would have to be next to each other, nothing in between.

Comment: Did you really mean to write $\left(_{70}C_{68}\right)$ or did you mean to write $\left(_{70}C_{58}\right)$?

Comment: @David K Good catch, it should have been 58.

Comment: You have the right solution and in fact an _optimal_ solution. I am not sure why you thought you were not correct (except the typo of course). @angryavian 's answer has similar working with explanation for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result was correct. You can confirm this by algebraically manipulating either your expression or one of the other answers until you are able to show they are equal.

Here's a derivation of the formula corresponding to the form in which you wrote it.

First consider how many ways $60$ of the $72$ buyers could buy houses if there were no restriction against Oscar and Patricia buying adjacent homes.
The set of buyers can be selected in $\binom{72}{60}$ ways,
and for each set of buyers the $60$ houses they buy can be selected in
$P^{300}_{60}$ ways (permutations of $60$ houses out of $300$, since order matters).
So there would be a total of

$$ \binom{72}{60} {P^{300}_{60}} $$

distinct arrangements.

Knowing that Oscar and Patricia will not buy adjacent houses, all of the
$ \binom{72}{60} {P^{300}_{60}} $ arrangements
we have found are valid *except* the ones in which Oscar and Patricia are adjacent.
So we must subtract the adjacent cases.
These occur only in the cases where both Oscar and Patricia are buyers.
So we only have to be concerned with the
$\binom{70}{58}$ subsets of buyers who include both Oscar and Patricia.

Now suppose we have a selection of $60$ buyers including Oscar and Patricia.
Take the numbers $1$ to $299$ and assign Oscar and Patricia (together)
to one of the numbers and the other $58$ buyers each to a unique number from among the remaining numbers.
If $n$ is the number Oscar and Patricia are assigned to,
Oscar and Patricia buy houses $n$ and $n+1$;
any other buyer assigned to a number $k < n$ buys house $k$,
and any other buyer assigned to a number $k > n$ buys house $k + 1.$

All of this so far can be done in $\binom{70}{58} P^{299}_{59}$ ways,
since for each of $\binom{70}{58}$ subsets
we are assigning each of $59$ identifiable "buying units" to
$299$ distinct integers.
But for each such assignment we can put Oscar in house $n$ and Patricia in house $n+1$ or vice versa, so the total number of possible assignments
including the choice of which houses Oscar and Patricia buy is

$$ 2 \binom{70}{58} P^{299}_{59}. $$

With a little effort you can confirm that every such assignment gives an arrangement of house purchases in which Oscar and Patricia buy adjacent houses,
and every arrangement in which Oscar and Patricia buy adjacent houses is generated by exactly one of these assignments.

So the total number of possible arrangements of house purchases in which
Oscar and Patricia are *not* neighbors is

$$ \binom{72}{60} {P^{300}_{60}} - 2 \binom{70}{58} P^{299}_{59}, $$

exactly as proposed in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Total number of arrangements: $\binom{72}{60} \binom{300}{60} 60!$. (This is the same as what you computed.)

Arrangements where Oscar and Patricia are neighbors: $\binom{70}{58} 299 \cdot 2 \cdot \binom{298}{58} 58!$.

- $\binom{70}{58}$ ways to choose a set of $58$ buyers besides Oscar and Patricia
- $299$ ways to choose a pair of adjacent houses for Oscar and Patricia
- $2$ ways to place Oscar and Patricia in the adjacent pair of houses
- $\binom{298}{58}$ ways to choose 58 houses for the remaining 58 buyers
- $58!$ ways to place the 58 buyers in the 58 bought houses.

Comment: @MathLover Thank you for catching both of my mistakes! I've corrected them.

Answer (score 2):

Cases: neither buy, P buys, O buys, or both buy.

If neither buy a house, there are 70 people, of whom 60 will buy, and for each group of people, there are ${300 \choose 60}$ subsets of the houses, and then there are $60!$ ways to arrange those 60 people among the 60 houses.  So if neither buy, we have $${70 \choose 60}\cdot {300 \choose 60} \cdot 60! = {70 \choose 60} \cdot P_{60}^{300}$$

Case:P buys, O does not. There are 70 other people of whom 59 are buyers.  We get
$${70 \choose 59}\cdot{300 \choose 60} \cdot 60! = {70 \choose 59}\cdot P_{60}^{300}$$

Case: O buys, P does not, same number as previous case.

Case: Both O and P buy.  If there were no restriction on location, we would have $${70 \choose 58}\cdot{300 \choose 60} \cdot 60! = {70 \choose 58}\cdot P_{60}^{300}$$
From this, we need to subtract the cases that are not allowed due to animosity.  Again we have ${70 \choose 58}$ ways to pick other people.  Selecting the possible houses is trickier. To find the cases to subtract, we choose $2$ adjacent houses for P and O, which can happen in $299$ ways.  Given that, we have $298$ houses for the other $58$ buyers.  We also can distribute those $58$ people however we like in the other $58$ houses. The number of forbidden cases is therefore:
$${70 \choose 58}\cdot 299 \cdot 2 \cdot P_{58}^{298}$$
Finally, my answer is
$${70 \choose 60}\cdot P_{60}^{300} + {70 \choose 59}\cdot P_{60}^{300}\cdot 2 + {70 \choose 58}\cdot P_{60}^{300} - {70 \choose 58}\cdot 299 \cdot 2 \cdot P_{58}^{298}$$
or
$$P_{60}^{300}\cdot \Big[ {70 \choose 60} + 2 \cdot {70 \choose 59} + {70 \choose 58}\Big]- {70 \choose 58}\cdot 299 \cdot 2 \cdot P_{58}^{298}$$

EDIT TO ADD: Others have pointed out a shorter way to get the result, by simply considering everything that could happen, all at once, and then subtracting only the forbidden cases.  At first I wasn't sure that that would give the same answer, but in Pascal's Triangle, $${70 \choose 60} + {70 \choose 59} = {71 \choose 60}$$
and $${70 \choose 59} + {70 \choose 58} = {71 \choose 59}$$
and $${71 \choose 60} + {71 \choose 59} = {72 \choose 60}$$ so we end up in the same place in the end.

Comment: ${70 \choose 60}\cdot P_{60}^{300} + {70 \choose 59}\cdot P_{60}^{300}\cdot 2 + {70 \choose 58}\cdot P_{60}^{300}$ is a long-winded way to write ${72 \choose 60}\cdot P_{60}^{300}$, and in my opinion the reasoning to derive that part of the formula is correspondingly overcomplicated.

Comment: I did consider factoring out the $P_{60}^{300}$ from the first three terms, and I do think I understand the shorter reasoning, but the identity of the two combinations expressions is a bit beyond me.  There always seem to be subtle twists in this kind of problem so I was doing my best to break it down carefully into understandable pieces.

Comment: Oh, I see it now, I think. It is two iterations of "add adjacent entries to get the entry below and between them in Pascal's triangle."  Two levels deep.

Comment: I believe this is actually a named theorem (for arbitrary number of iterations) but I forget the name.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) just calls it "the recursion formula".